# How do I vertically center the text within a flex element?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment, text-alignment, flexbox

Is there a special way to vertically center text in an element using flexboxes (or other pure CSS)?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WK_of_Angmar/JZZWg/

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <section id="a">Test1</section>
    <section id="b">Test2</section>
</div>
```

```
#a {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
#b {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    min-height: 3em;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#a {
    background-color: blue;
}
#main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: inherit;
}

body {height: inherit;}
html {height: 100%;}
```

Comment: Accidentally asked here instead of Stack Overflow. Would appreciate a move. :-)

Comment: With flexbox you can vertically center a flex element inside a flex container, but flexbox doesn't provide support for centering text content within a flex element. You'll need to use the same tricks as for centering text in a non-flex element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `line-height` is one solution, here's the **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/JZZWg/7/)** to Fiddle.

**Update:** I took a little more interest in the flex model and found the centering properties, so I guess this makes a better solution for you (although not that neat and elegant because of all the prfixes). Here is the **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/JZZWg/27/)** to Fiddle using flex properties for alignment.

And here is a **[link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/)** that explains the usage of the properties.

Comment: Ahh, can't believe I forgot about this. If nobody provides a more elegant solution, I'll accept.

Comment: Fair enough though there is another option to go with (using vertical-align and an image) the line-height is probably more elegant. Here is a link to an article that describes both solutions: http://hu.je/example

Comment: For a single line of text that will never wrap around to a second line, and is inside a container with a fixed height, this is the most elegant solution possible. Does it suit your requirements? (if not, you'll need a different solution)

Comment: I don't expect the content to wrap, but that does not account for what could/should happen on edge cases (where it can wrap). As for now, this is what I'm going for, but it does not completely suit my requirement. However, there are hacky workarounds to make this a satisfactory solution. CSS is an absolute mess for creating layouts.