# How do I center div horizontally and vertically within a div using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

How do I center (horizontally) and middle (vertically) a `div` within another `div` using flexbox?

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19026884/2317532) Q/A [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15593669/2317532), but are too specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nA5YJ/)

In a flexbox, setting `margin` to `auto` will set the margin automatically for both the horizontal and vertical axis.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {width:100%;height:100%;}
.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid red;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto; /* Auto margin for both horizontal and vertical axis */
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```